# How to remove text generated from php echo on a page reload

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML page with nothing but a form on that allows me to search a database and save the query results in an array. I then go through the array and echo out the results of each field in the table as plan text.

however if the page is reloaded the results of the last query just stay on the page until I submit a new query.

I want this text to disappear so the page looks like it does the first time it is opened/ before any text has been outputted to the page.

when I reload the popup 'do you want to resubmit form data appears'

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details than this...

Comment: I assume a pop-up dialogue along the lines of "Do you want to re-send form data" happens when you hit reload before the screen reloads?

Comment: @DeanRather - A search does not require a POST to occur. See Google, which uses GET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the search results again, because when you refresh the page you are submitting again the search form.

You can't avoid that as long as you stay on the same page.

Comment: I didn't realise the form was re submitting, I thought the page was just retaining the text

Answer (score 1):

You can actually fix this.

Every time the page is loaded, generate a random number, and put that into a session variable. Also put it into the search form, using a hidden field.

When the form is submitted, check whether the number in the session is the same as the one coming in from the form. If they are not, don't do the search, as this search has already "expired".

Comment: How does that "fix" a refresh?

Comment: IMHO his problem is not with refresh itself, but the fact that as the refresh reissues the post, the page will not be empty after the reload.